# Disable link function for PART of the content in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

Is it possible to disable just a portion of the content inside an anchor tag from triggering the link?

**Ex.**

```
<a href="/some-path" >I am a link <span>but I am not</span></a>
```

Clicking on the "I am a link" portion would result in standard anchor tag function, taking you to `/some-path`, but clicking on the "but I am not" portion would do nothing - or perhaps an event listener could be added to that part and do something else.

The use-case for this is where a JS script dynamically appends "edit" icons to all copy on a page and an event listener is added to the icons that allows you to edit the respective text. The issue is that some copy happens to be inside an anchor tag so clicking on the icon inside the tag triggers the link along with the event listener and takes you off the page.

Comment: Sure, you could a click event handler to the span that simply prevents the event and stops propagation

Comment: But from a usability point of view, it's slightly unexpected behavior if I as a user click part of a link and it doesn't act like a link.

Comment: this part would be an edit icon styled differently so I think that would mitigate users' expectations

Comment: If it's styled differently then does it have to be inside the <a> tag in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible. In the click handler for the element use event.preventDefault(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

An example is as follows:

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", 
  function(event) {
    alert("I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave")
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: The downvote (from me) is primarily because this answer is mostly a link only answer.

Comment: This should really be a comment as it's not a complete answer

Comment: I added a usage example.

Comment: The essential part of the answer is to use event.preventDefault() in the click handler. The answer is short because the problem is simple.